# Is there any way to inspect image by URI in development process

Tags: android, android-studio, uri

I have uri to image (content://........./my-image.jpg). For debug purpose it would be great if i had possibility to look on this image. Is there any quick way to open it with android studio/ADB or any other tools?

Answer (score 0):

One useful tool is [Chrome Inspect tool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/). 
You can inspect the elements as if they were **HTML**, see your network requests to the server and aslo inspect your database, if you have one.